# How to take JSON Input and turn it into const array in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, import, frontend

I am pretty new to react but I am trying to basically import data from a JSON string and basically save it in a const using my function importData(). I don't even know where to start. Right now, I basically just have a text area that pops up where you can paste in a JSON string and a const array.
Here is my sample array:

```
const arr = [
{"firstName": "Andrew", "lastName":"Yang", "status": "Available", "startDate": "2019-06-01", "votes": 100},
{"firstName": "Joe", "lastName": "Biden", "status":"available", "startDate": "2020-01-01", "votes": 455},
{"firstName": "Pete", "lastName": "Buttegig", "status":"available", "startDate": "2018-01-19", "votes": 300},
{"firstName": "Bernie", "lastName": "Sanders", "status":"available", "startDate": "2001-11-01", "votes": 200},]
```

And here is the function I am trying to write. I would love some help in seeing how I can write this function so the userInput in the text area will become the new const arr.

```
function importData() {
return (
    <Component initialState={{ isShown: false }}>
    {({ state, setState }) => (
        <Pane>
        <Dialog
            isShown={state.isShown}
            title="Dialog title"
            onCloseComplete={() => setState({ isShown: false })}
            confirmLabel="Custom Label"
        >
            <textarea
                name="input"
                type="text"
            />
        </Dialog>

        <Button onClick={() => setState({ isShown: true })}>Show Dialog</Button>
        </Pane>
    )}
    </Component>
)
```

}

Comment: I would suggest learn basics of react. For example what are states and how it works in react. It will help alot in going through. In react everything revolve around `states` so you need to save in `const` . You need to update in states

Comment: Kind of hard to understand what you are trying to achieve, do you mean you want to use textarea for user to enter json string and you want to convert it into an array ?

Comment: Yeah! That's exactly what I am trying to do :)